# VM456:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: wndow is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new at javascript, I am trying to make a script to reload a web page after some time but when the time is complete the error shows up and it does not reload the page.

```
    var url = window.location.href;
console.log("My url: "+url);
console.log("Ten seconds");
setTimeout(function(){reload();}, 10000);

function reload(){
    console.log("Refreshing to... " + url);
    wndow.location.href = url;
}
```

I do not know what to do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake.

**wn**dow.location.href = url;

Comment: Yes! I've just have seen that 'facepalm'

Comment: @JhonatanRico if you consider this is the correct answer, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Don't waste time on typo questions. Just vote to close them.